# Local host displaying blankpage without any errors in react bootstrap routing and not linking to different pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I created my app with create-react-app and trying to use react-router on it. but it's not working at all.

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import 'react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js';
import "./App.css";
import { Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import AppHeader from "./components/header";
import About from "./components/About";
import AppSlide from "./components/slide";
import Projects from "./components/projects";
import Contact from "./components/pages/Contact";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import Appfooter from "./components/footer";

`function App() {
      
  return (
    `<div className="App">
     
      <header id="header">
        <AppHeader />`
      </header>
      <Routes>
         <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
         <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects/>}/>
         <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
         <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
        </Routes>
      <main>
        <AppSlide />
        <about />
        <projects/>

        <Contact />
      </main>
      <footer id="footer">
        <Appfooter />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
 
}
export default App;

**Index.js file**
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

**navigation bar code**
import React from "react";

import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import NavDropdown from "react-bootstrap/NavDropdown";

import logo from "../components/images/real.png";

export default function AppHeader() {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="bg-body-tertiary">
  
      <Container>
      
      <Navbar expanded="lg" className="phone-info " id="phone"><span>+254 727 411269 |+254 724 933 760 | +254 719 577 339</span></Navbar>
      
      <Navbar.Brand href="/" id="logos"><img src={logo} className="logo" alt="VEHUSA" width={300} height={0}/></Navbar.Brand>
      
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <div className="fusion">
      <div className="fusion-wrapper">
      <a className="facebook"  href="https://www.facebook.com/VHSacco" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
      <a className="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/i/flow/login?redirect_after_login=%2FVeronaHSacco"  target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><i className="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      
      <a className="linkedin"  href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/VHS/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><i className="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      <a className="mail"  href="mailto:info@veronahurumasacco.co.ke  " target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><i className="fa fa-envelope" ></i></a>
     </div>
     </div>
      
          <Nav activeKey="/home">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <Nav.Link class="nav-link" id="navlink" href="/">
                  Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </Nav.Link>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <NavDropdown title="About Us" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="/about">Who are we</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#fusion">Board of directors</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Management Team</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Affiliates and Partners</NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <NavDropdown title="What we do" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="/projects">
                    Products and services
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">
                    Our Business
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </li>

              <NavDropdown title="Projects" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                  Ongoing projects
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">
                  Past projects
                </NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
              <Nav.Link href="/contact.js">Contact</Nav.Link>
            </ul>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}



**Contact page**
import React from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export default function Contact() {
  return (
    <section id="contact" className="block contact-block">
      <Container fluid>
        <div className="title-holder">
          <h2>Contact us</h2>
          <div className="subtitle">We would love to Hear From you</div>
        </div>
        <Form className="contact-form">
          <Row>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Form.Control type='text' placeholder="Enter your full name" required/>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Form.Control type='email' placeholder="Enter your email address" required/>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Form.Control type='tel' placeholder="Enter your phone number" required/>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12}>
            <Form.Control as='textarea' placeholder="Enter your message" required /> 
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <div className='btn-holder'>
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
}

**About page**
import React from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';


import img1 from "../assets/images/mans.webp";


export default function About() {
  return (
    <section id="about" className="block about-block">
      <Container fluid>
        <div className="title-holder">
          <h2 className="now">About Us</h2>
          <div className="subtitle">learn more about us</div>
        </div>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={6}>
            <Image variant="top" src={img1} />
          </Col>
          <Col sm={6}>
            <p><br/>
            Vehusa Housing Company Ltd is a fully owned subsidiary of Verona Huruma Sacco Society Limited (hereinafter VHS Sacco). Vehusa was established to enable Sacco members to acquire affordable housing solutions by pooling resources and benefiting economies of scale.
           </p>
            <p>Its main objective is to improve the living standard of people living and working in the Kariobangi Parish and its environs through pooling resources.
            It has tremendously grown to a Sacco with a membership of over 20,000 from all walks of life and enlarged its wings beyond Nairobi.
            </p>
             
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae
              alias ex error distinctio laudantium recusandae, iure. Vel nisi
              soluta, minus consectetur reiciendis laborum, laudantium
              perspiciatis quos molestias quam eum.
            </p>
            
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
}
```

It is supposed to display different pages for contact page, about page, home page and projects this being the home page.

[picture of home page with the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey31C.jpg)

Where could I be wrong?

Comment: If you manually update the path in the address bar to `"/home"`, `"/projects"`, `"/about"`, or `"/contact"` do those routes and content render? I don't see where you render any `Link` components to navigate to these pages.

Comment: So of the `App` component code, what ***is*** being rendered? Anything? Your post implies the `Home` homepage component is rendered. Can you [edit] to share a complete [mcve] that includes your index files so we can see what is rendered?

Comment: @Drew Reese I have only updated path to contact apge only

Comment: Well, regardless of the URL path, there is other content that is unconditionally rendered that you should be able to see. Are you sure there are no errors in the browser console? Try simplifying what you are trying to render until you get something to render to the DOM, and then incrementally add content back one at-a-time to see where it breaks, then repeat the process in *that* component until you find the problem code.

Answer (score -2):

navigate to `index.js` and Wrap the whole app router with

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

  <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
```